# Delayed job in jsp/servlet application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet in my application used for uploading files. I then want to process the file which could take up to 5 minutes. By having this code in the servlet am I potentially blocking incoming request? Either way I think I would prefer to create a background job to handle processing the file. What is the best method for handling this? My application is running on Tomcat.

Comment: Create a thread to read and write file for each request

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using multi thread here:

One thread will take care to read every line of the file and insert it into a BlockingQueue in order to be processed.
Another thread(s) will take the elements from this queue and process them.
To implement this multi thread work, it would be better using ExecutorService interface and passing Runnable instances, each should implement each task. Remember to have only a single task to read the file.

I would recommend never do heavy work in servlet. Instead, fire an asynchronous task e.g. via JMS call